# Download dependencies from remote repository without modifyng the pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository

I work on a project which has remote dependencies which I can't access (corporate stuff). I got those dependencies mirrored and I managed to upload them to my GitLab package registry. I want to use the uploaded dependencies in my project, but here's the catch: the client doesn't want to modify the pom.xml because they have a CI/CD for it and if I modify the pom.xml their stages will fail.

So my question: is there some way to set dependencies to an alternative remote repository without modifying the pom.xml? Or at least check if maven can download from the client repository and if it fails it should try my GitLab registry.

Comment: if I get your question right, you can try settings.xml -  mvn install -s settings.xml - https://www.baeldung.com/maven-settings-xml

Comment: Is there a repository manager in use? Why do you mirror them in GitLab package registry?

Comment: @Alexandr Arhipov I tried the the Repository part before, but for some reason doesn't work .

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately not. The reason of mirroring is that I don't have access for it, I asked another department to mirror for me to atleast try to build it, and run it locally and get started with my actual project which contains these inaccessible  dependencies. Complex story sadly.

Comment: That does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `<mirror>` in the `settings.xml`, this will take precedence over the repositories defined in the `pom.xml`.